# React app returning a blank page on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github

i created a portfolio website and deployed to github pages but it's returning a blank page, i have updated the homepage and scripts in package.json, i tried deploying via vercel and netlify and it's the same error.

the github link is https://github.com/dayolovesruby/MyPortfolio

the github pages link is https://dayolovesruby.github.io/MyPortfolio/

n.b the website is working well in my localhost

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `dayolovesruby` part from the `homepage` in `package.json`.